# jquery - each function order by class number

Tags: jquery

i have a function, which search for class `step1, step2, step3....`

```
$(this).find('[class*="step"]').each(function(){

}
```

I want to run function ordering by class number, Like:

```
<div class="myclass">
    <div class="step4">..</div>
    <div class="step1">..</div>
    <div class="step3">..</div>
    <div class="step2">..</div>
</div
```

Now first run, step1 then step2 then step3 and so on

I tried this code:

```
var i=1;
$(this).find('.step'+i).each(function(){
    i++;
}
```

is my above code is oky?? cuz I am running a each function on a single selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to us a loop

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    var step = $('.step' + i);
    //do something with step
}
```